# Stopping ASP.NET MVC from emitting data-val-number validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My (View)model has a BillRate field that shows e.g. "$123.00"

```
    [Display(Name = "Bill Rate")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public Decimal BillRate { get; set; }
```

Due to the ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, this shows a '$' sign and thus it is not a valid Decimal, and the (client side) validation fails when I tab out of the textbox.

I work around this by adding my own custom `ValidationAttribute`

```
    [DecimalSymbols(ErrorMessage = "Invalid currency")]
```

where `DecimalSymbols` which strips symbols and then parses the remaining digits:

```
public sealed class DecimalSymbolsAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

This seems to work well.  However, the emitted HTML still has `data-val-number` attribute, in addition to my `data-val-decimalsymbols` attribute:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-decimalsymbols="Invalid currency" data-val-number="The field Bill Rate must be a number." id="BillRate" name="BillRate" type="text" value="$82.80" />
```

The `data-val-number` attribute causes jQuery validation to fail because the '$' makes the string not a number. I don't need this attribute anymore, but how do I tell ASP.NET MVC not to put it?  I've tried using EditorFor, TextBoxFor, and TextBox, and it is put regardless.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DataFormatString = "{0:c}"` is making your value come back as a currency value with a preceding $. One way you could tell MVC not to attach that validator is make your own extension method to produce the `HtmlString`.

Alternatively, use `ApplyFormatInEditMode = false` to not put the $ in the string in an editing mode.

Comment: I tried to work around not creating a custom Editor Template by 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[data-val-decimalsymbols]").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("data-val-number");
        });
    });

but this did not help.  I think keeping the '$' in the editing mode is attractive, but can't believe ASP.NET even offers ApplyFormatInEditMode = true because it simply doesn't work with validation.